# How to retrieve the particular object field in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have rest call something like this when I am getting result I am getting in string format something like this ,

```
   public String getData(String value) throws ParseException {
                final String url = "https://v1/supplier/suggest/{value}";
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("value", value);
                HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(this.getAuthHeaders());
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                ResponseEntity<String> tpBody = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class, params);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(tpBody.getBody());
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("data");
        if (jsonArray.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No Data in JsonArray");
        } else {
            Object object = jsonArray.get(0);
            System.out.println(object.toString());
        }
    }
        
            }
```

Response:-

```
{"value":"DRAGON","datas":9.5}
```

Now from this string I want only  datas field value  , like suppose only 9.5

Any sort of help is appreciated .

Comment: You need to parse JSON. You can use `javax.json` library.

Comment: You need to parse the message and get the required field from that object. I would suggest to look into JasonPath library which will make your job easy. It has capability to parse the Json string and get the required field from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        String datas = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("datas");
        System.out.println(datas);
    }
```

Comment: Depending on your requirement, either you parse (sample code in other comment) the body or directly convert it to the DTO Object and get required value (Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template#2-retrieving-pojo-instead-of-json).

It's recommended that you use WebClient because moving forward, RestTemplate will be deprecated in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response that you are getting is nothing but a Map. So I would suggest using the Jackson library to convert the json to a Map and then get the value for your key 'datas' - something like below:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(object.toString(),Map.class);
   Double datasValue = (Double) map.get("datas");
```

Dependency for Jackson is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
```